# Django - from function view to generic class view

Tags: django, django-views

I had this `function based view` and i'm trying to transform it in a `generic class view` as such:

> Original:

```
def view_events (request):

    template ='appform/view_events.html'
    items = Event.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
    pages = pagination(request,items, num = 10)
    print(pages)
    context = {
        'items': pages[0],
        'page_range': pages[1],
    }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

> Generic Class view:

```
class ViewEvents(generic.ListView):

    template_name = 'app/view_events.html'
    model = Event
    context_object_name = 'events'
    pagination = ???

    def get_queryset(self):

        return Event.objects.filter(owner = self.request.user)
```

EDIT : i've used [this](http://www.mastercode.online/tutorials/language/tutorial_series/tutorial/how-to-django-blog-application-how-to-add-django-pagination/) for the pagination, which is a custom paginator. the question i'm trying to ask is how do i implement it in a `generic class view`?

Later EDIT: This got it working, in case it might ever be of use to someone:)

```
class ViewEvents(generic.ListView):

    template_name = 'app/view_events.html'
    model = Event
    context_object_name = 'items'

    def get_queryset(self):

        return Event.objects.filter(owner = self.request.user)


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        context = super(ViewEvents, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        objects_all = Event.objects.filter(owner = self.request.user)
        pages = pagination(self.request, objects_all, num = 10)
        context['items'] = pages[0]
        context['page_range'] = pages[1]

        return  context
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. List views are already paginated, and you have done what you need to do by defining `get_queryset`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman i was using a custom paginator (link included in edit). i'll try to further make the question more clear. thx!

Comment: You can define [`paginator_class`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.paginator_class) to point to your custom paginator.